# Capturing android camera with VideoCapture in OpenCV2.3.1

Tags: android, opencv, camera, android-ndk, video-capture

I'm trying to use VideoCapture in my OpenCV native application. To 
construct my application I followed instructions released with 
OpenCV2.3.1 release, so I have an Android.mk file to build my app and 
a Builder in eclipse to do it directly from eclipse. 
Everything works fine, compiling and linking other openCV modules, but when I use VideoCapture I get a linking error like this:

> SharedLibrary  : liblivecamera.so 
>   C:/Development/android-opencv-wsp/VideoCamLibAndroid_v0.1/obj/local/ 
>   armeabi-v7a/libopencv_highgui.a(cap_android.o): In function 
>   `CvCapture_Android::convertYUV2BGR(int, int, unsigned char const*, 
>   cv::Mat&, bool, bool)':  cap_android.cpp: 
>   (.text._ZN17CvCapture_Android14convertYUV2BGREiiPKhRN2cv3MatEbb 
>   *+0x1c6): undefined reference to`cv::cvtColor(cv::_InputArray const&,  cv::_OutputArray const&, int, int)'  cap_android.cpp: 
>   (.text._ZN17CvCapture_Android14convertYUV2BGREiiPKhRN2cv3MatEbb 
>   +0x1f8): undefined reference to `cv::cvtColor(cv::_InputArray const&,  cv::_OutputArray const&, int, int)'  collect2: ld returned 1 exit
>   status  make: *** [/cygdrive/c/Development/android-opencv-wsp/ 
>   VideoCamLibAndroid_v0.1/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/liblivecamera.so] Error 
>   1*

If I use opencv2.3.0 I can make it work (compiling with CMake), but I really need to use OCV2.3.1 and its new functionality.

Has anyone successfully used VideoCapture module with OpenCV2.3.1?

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same problem and after bashing my head against the wall for several hours I finally found a solution !

Apparently, There is an error in the `OpenCV.mk` provided with the OpenCV 2.3.1.

The following line:

`OPENCV_MODULES := contrib calib3d objdetect features2d video imgproc highgui ml legacy flann core`

Should be replaced with:

`OPENCV_MODULES := contrib legacy objdetect calib3d features2d video highgui ml imgproc flann core`

It looks very similar but there is a slight difference if you look at the order of the modules.

You can understand the logic of this change by taking a look at the `OpenCVConfig.cmake` file which states as follows:
`#libraries order is very important because linker from Android NDK is one-pass linker`

If it's so important why wasn't it included in the original `OpenCV.mk` ?????